# Gradle: Exclude distribution zip task from assemble

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm using the [distribution plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#distribution_plugin). When I run a *gradle build*, which depends on *gradle assemble*, both `distTar` and `distZip` are triggered, and I end up with both a tarball and a zip file of my distribution. I only need a tarball. running both is time and space consuming (the project distribution is very large).

What would be a clean way to exclude `distZip` from a high level gradle build? I know I can use `gradle build -x distZip` but I want to run plain `gradle build`. I know dependencies can be excluded with `build.dependsOn.remove(<name>)` but I saw it described as not-recommended.

Thanks.

Comment: For others searching: the application plugin implicitly applies the distribution plugin.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can try:

```
distZip.enabled = false
```

Comment: When you also use the [maven plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html),  `gradle install` will fail, because it tries to upload the zip. The solution is to also remove the zip artifacts, like this: `configurations.archives.artifacts.removeAll {it.file =~ 'zip'}`

Comment: I suppose I should add this to the build file (e.g. build.gradle.kts)? How can I get it to produce a single file instead of the zip or tar that contains a folder structure with stuff inside?

Answer (score 2):

One of our gradle builds has starting failing due to this issue. As mentioned by TmTom above the full solution was

```
task deleteZip {
    configurations.archives.artifacts.removeAll {it.file =~ 'zip'}
}

tasks.install.dependsOn(deleteZip)
```

If tars are also being troublesome add:

```
    configurations.archives.artifacts.removeAll {it.file =~ 'tar'}
```

Comment: This was close for me, but I needed a doLast block: `task doNotUploadDistribution { doLast { configurations.archives.artifacts.removeAll {it.classifier == 'distribution'} } }`

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured additional distributions like this

```
    distributions {
        mySpecialDistribution {
            contents {
                duplicatesStrategy = 'INCLUDE'
                ...
            }
    }
```

you have to disable the distribution specific task:

```
mySpecialDistributionDistZip.enabled = false
```

In order to disable the distZip for all distributions, you can do the following:

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { 
    graph -> graph.allTasks.findAll { it.name ==~ /.*DistZip/ }*.enabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recipe for **build.gradle.kts**:

```
tasks.distZip {
    enabled = false
}

tasks.distTar {
    enabled = false
}
```

It's ok if you don't need tar/zip at all, and all what you need is the `install` folder to create docker container, for example. Because it's not possible to run this task anymore:

```
./gradlew distZip
...

> Task :distZip SKIPPED
```